# src/lxml/etree_defs.h:9:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, pip

1. I am running the following comand for installing the packages in that file "
   `pip install -r requirements.txt --download-cache=~/tmp/pip-cache`".
2. requirement.txt contains pacakages like

```
# Data formats
# ------------
PIL==1.1.7 # 

html5lib==0.90
httplib2==0.7.4
lxml==2.3.1

# Documentation
# -------------
Sphinx==1.1
docutils==0.8.1

# Testing
# -------
behave==1.1.0
dingus==0.3.2
django-testscenarios==0.7.2
mechanize==0.2.5
mock==0.7.2
testscenarios==0.2
testtools==0.9.14
wsgi_intercept==0.5.1
```

while comming to install "lxml" packages i am getting the following eror

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-testproject>=0.1.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_testproject-0.1.1-py2.7.egg (from django-testscenarios==0.7.2->-r requirements.txt (line 33))
Installing collected packages: lxml, Sphinx, docutils, behave, dingus, mock, testscenarios, testtools, South
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    Building lxml version 2.3.1.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: /bin/sh: xslt-config: command not found

    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:239:0:
    src/lxml/etree_defs.h:9:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/root/Projects/ir/build/lxml/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-SwjFm3-record/install-record.txt:
    Building lxml version 2.3.1.

Building without Cython.

ERROR: /bin/sh: xslt-config: command not found



** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **



Using build configuration of libxslt

running install

running build

running build_py

copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_dictmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:239:0:

src/lxml/etree_defs.h:9:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/root/Projects/ir/build/lxml/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-SwjFm3-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Can anyone check and guide me what would be the problem and why?Any package missing to install.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Install libxslt-devel & libxml2-devel using

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

After installing follow the above one

Comment: Notice for Ubuntu 13.04 users: if you have libxml2 already installed and upgraded to version 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.3 you need to downgrade it to 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.1 by typing the command sudo apt-get install libxml2=2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.1 otherwise the libxml2-dev wont be installed due version dependency.

Comment: What is the different between libxml2 and libxml? Thanks!

Comment: @Honghe.Wu here you can find the difference details: http://xmlsoft.org/FAQ.html. In short, go for libxml2

Comment: after performing this it gives below error : EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

Comment: I installed the two libraries, and still got the error.  Logged off and back on, and still got the error.  The make file is looking in /usr/include for libxml, but that is nested inside a libxml2 directory.  Linking to libxml from /usr/include did the trick `sudo ln -s libxml2/libxml libxml`.

Comment: this is the answer for Debian Jessie too

Comment: For those using Alpine Linux (probably in Docker), the command is: apk add install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev

Answer (score 56):

1. Install Cython using

   `easy_install Cython`
2. After completion of cython, install libxslt-devel & libxml2-devel using

   `yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel`

This worked for me.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer (use sudo apt-get debian/ubuntu)

Comment: @roshan: right, sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev

Comment: for amazon linux, `sudo yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devell` solved for me, thx

Comment: Cython was the missing link for me, after installing the libraries. It's just `-dev` for the packages on Raspbian though. Installing cython was tricky... I ended up having to use `sudo pip3 install Cython --install-option="--no-cython-compile"` for it to work properly. `sudo pip3 install Cython` alone crashed, and `easy_install3` didn't do anything

Answer (score 10):

The selected answer is right but I just wanted to add for those who use Fedora: `libxslt1` is called `libxslt` when using dnf. So the command is:

```
sudo dnf install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
```

`devel` for dnf is the same as `dev` for apt-get.

Answer (score 7):

The certified answer works perfectly. But just adding the installation command for alpine to install libxslt-devel & libxml2-devel

```
apk add --update libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

Comment: That might be obvious, but generally `--update` is not needed.

Answer (score 6):

without sudo rights you can install lxml with:

```
STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml
```

As mentioned in the [lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/installation.html#using-lxml-with-python-libxml2)