# Installing lxml in virtualenv via pip install error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed

Tags: python, linux, gcc, virtualenv, lxml

when I activate virtualenv and type 'pip install lxml' installation process crashes with message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: There is a some required packages missing problem. Please install this packages to your system.I'm using centos and i have install it using yum command. `libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel`

Answer (score 4):

The error you have to pay attention to is the first "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz": tnhat means you don't have zlib-dev installed. Depending on your linux distribution it could be named zlib-dev or zlib1g-dev in Ubuntu, I don't know in other distros.

Answer (score 0):

Installing those dependencies fixed it for me (Debian 7):

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

source: [src/lxml/etree_defs.h:9:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759150/src-lxml-etree-defs-h931-fatal-error-libxml-xmlversion-h-no-such-file-or-di)

Answer (score 0):

From https://askubuntu.com/questions/627140/cannot-install-lxml-on-ubuntu-14

```
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

For RHEL7/Fedora/CentOS in order to install lxml you need to:

```
YUM/DNF install libxml2 libxslt
```

...and possibly:

```
YUM/DNF install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel
```

Cheers!