# "error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1" in virtualenv

Tags: python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, linux-mint

Environment: Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon.

This error is displayed:

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

when attempting the following in a `virtualenv`:

```
pip install lxml
pip install pillow
pip install pycrypto
pip install pymongo (fails but still shows in pip freeze)
```

There are several solutions here that recommend installing `python2.7-dev`:

[Installing Pillow error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675977/installing-pillow-error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-g)

[Installing lxml in virtualenv via pip install error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239816/installing-lxml-in-virtualenv-via-pip-install-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-g)

[Pillow installation error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347489/pillow-installation-error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1)

[fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

I am confused by this recommendation however because it is my understanding that using something like:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

would add this to the main *system* instance of Python, rather that the one in `virtualenv`.  (see - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56392/92486)

Can I add `python2.7-dev` just to the `virtualenv` version of Python?

Comment: This should be moved to ServerFault ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I installed `python2.7-dev` via Synaptic Package Manager in Linux Mint 17.

I could then accomplish the following in `virtualenv`:

```
pip install pillow
pip install pycrypto
```

And then I installed `libxml2-dev` and `libxslt1-dev` via Synaptic and could accomplish the following:

```
pip install lxml
```

I also did this so that the pymongo install didn't have any errors:

```
pip uninstall pymongo
pip install pymongo  # i defined the version i needed ie pip install pymongo==2.6.2
```

I'm still confused how this fixes the problem, because I thought `virtualenv` was an isolated environment.  Any clarification about this appreciated.

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 14.10 as well!
Thanks a ton @user1063287, you saved my day! :)

Comment: Glad to hear @DhruvSingh

Comment: From the docs: "`virtualenv` is a tool to create isolated Python environments." What they mean is isolated in terms of *Python packages*. C libraries, headers, build tools, etc. from the outside system are visible, even your Python binaries. It's not a virtual machine or a separate Python binary installation.

Comment: for 'pillow' you also need `sudo apt-get install  build-essential libjpeg-dev libzlib-dev`

Answer (score 20):

Most of the time these are dependency-issues.

Following the stack-trace of the gcc compiler one can see the missing files. Sometimes installing the Python development packages is not enough.

For example:
I tried to do `pip install requests[security]` in my virtualenv *foo*. This is the result that the pip-installer gave me.

```
Failed building wheel for cryptography
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cffi
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/99/e7/9a/68b1c8ca6f6f92b5feebd4d9434f50712b84f6a66d1285ea21
Successfully built cffi
Failed to build cryptography
Installing collected packages: cffi, cryptography, pyOpenSSL, ndg-httpsclient, requests
Running setup.py install for cryptography
Complete output from command /opt/foo/django-cms-virtualenv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-eZaLAG/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BwgYTp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/foo/django-cms-virtualenv/include/site/python2.7/cryptography:
running install
running build
running build_py
running egg_info
writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
building '_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.o
src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__pycache__/_Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.c:217:25: fatal error: openssl/aes.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
 #include <openssl/aes.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The important part is the: `#include <openssl/aes.h>`

The compiler makes pretty clear that it is demanding this file - but it is not there in the filesystem.

Knowing that, the only thing left to do is: **install the needed libraries!**

1. Find out which package is needed for your distribution:
   e.g. for Ubuntu you can go to [The Ubuntu Package Search Site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=aes.h&searchon=contents) and enter the missing file you are looking for. In this case "**aes.h**"
2. Install the needed packages using your distributions package management tool:
   e.g. for Ubuntu:

   `aptitude install libssl-dev`
3. Retry with pip in your virtualenv:

   `pip install requests[security]`

Comment: Yes! `install libssl-dev` solved my issues when trying to install bpython an a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 box. Thanks a million!

Comment: in my case the missing lib was `libffi-dev`

Answer (score 5):

Work for me :
Just install python2.7-dev first 
`sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev`

Comment: Worked for me also! So helpful xD

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04.1 this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the installation of lxml was failing on compilation. I followed the instructions for installation of lxml and reduced the compiler optimizations:

```
sudo CFLAGS="-O0"  pip install lxml
```

After doing this, the compile of lxml succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a problem in the pip. To solve, try:

> sudo apt-get remove python-pip

To install pip, securely download get-pip.py.

> https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
>
> sudo python get-pip.py

Answer (score 0):

The `cffi` library needs `libffi-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
```

and then

```
pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, 12.04, python2.7.6 for package **lxml**

```
sudo pip install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
sudo pip install lxml
```

Comment: i think you meant sudo apt-get install instead of pip?