# Ubuntu Eclipse libxml2 error : fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, eclipse, libxml2

I want to use libxml2 in my eclipse project. I can use this library on command line by "

> g++ main.cpp -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -o output
>   "

But I can't use on eclipse.I add C++ Build->Setting->GCC C Compiler->Includes

> -I/usr/include/libxml2
>   and I add C++ Build->Setting->GCC C++ Linker->library 
>   -lxml2

But When I build my project, I get an error via

> libxml/parser.h:15:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

Comment: The problem is solved!
I add  /usr/include/libxml2 to C++ Compiler-> Includes and xml2(not -lxml2)  
to GCC C++ Linker->library

Answer (score 45):

This is because libs are not complete. You should install them.

[Here's one thread that might be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759150/src-lxml-etree-defs-h931-fatal-error-libxml-xmlversion-h-no-such-file-or-di)

One solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

For Redhat/Centos/Fedora:

```
yum install libxml-devel
```

Comment: ugh...I keep getting `No package libxml-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: On my end these packages are already installed but still I get the same error. I had to add the following argument to g++ to fix it: `-I/usr/include/libxml2`

Comment: Right answer. On CentOS 7: `yum install libxslt-devel libxml++-devel libxml2-devel`

Comment: This answer saved me a lot on Ubuntu 20.04! Thanks again!