# command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 when try to install lxml

Tags: python, gcc, lxml

i am new in python and i try to use openpyxl to process excel.And when i use `sudo pip install lxml` , i met this kind of wrong info:

```
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:239:0:

/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:14:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Rolling back uninstall of lxml
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759150/src-lxml-etree-defs-h931-fatal-error-libxml-xmlversion-h-no-such-file-or-di and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254475/ubuntu-eclipse-libxml2-error-fatal-error-libxml-xmlversion-h-no-such-file-or and etc and etc.

Comment: @alecxe I dont know the error message is the same. And why only my question is marked as duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

you need some other package to install, see [here](http://lxml.de/installation.html) for detail.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```