# Can't Include LibXML2 Files in a CMake C++ Project (using QtCreator IDE)

Tags: c++, qt-creator, libxml2, mlpack

I'm working on a Cmake based C++ project in QtCreator. I am trying to use mlpack in my project, but as soon as I include the line `#include <mlpack/core.hpp>` to my only source file, I get an error pertaining to some libxml files that are included by mlpack/core.hpp:

```
    In file included from /usr/local/include/mlpack/core/util/save_restore_utility.hpp:26:0,
             from /usr/local/include/mlpack/core.hpp:171,
             from /home/revinci/code/workspaces/qt_ws/Semantic_Perception/src/features_slic.cpp:18:
    /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:15:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
    #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
```

Now, I went into `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/` and found `parser.h` with the line `#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>` in it.
So, I saw that `xmlversion.h` and `parser.h` are in the same folder and tried a hack: I changed the `#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>` in `parser.h` to `#include "xmlversion.h"` only to get the following error:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:15:0,
             from /usr/local/include/mlpack/core/util/save_restore_utility.hpp:26,
             from /usr/local/include/mlpack/core.hpp:171,
             from /home/revinci/code/workspaces/qt_ws/Semantic_Perception/src/features_slic.cpp:18:
    /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h:13:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlexports.h: No such file or directory
    #include <libxml/xmlexports.h>
```

Which is basically telling me that it can't find `xmlexports.h` (included by `xmlversion.h`). More importantly, `xmlexports.h` is in the same directory as `xmlversion.h` and `parser.h`!

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254475/ubuntu-eclipse-libxml2-error-fatal-error-libxml-xmlversion-h-no-such-file-or) and installed `libxml2-dev` (again) and `libxslt1-dev`, but my problem wasn't solved.

I think this may have something to do with specifying my include paths correctly. I've tried to add `/usr/include/libxml2` to the various path environment variables (`PATH`, `INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPATH`) that are present in my build environment in QtCreator, but to no avail. My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
    project(Semantic_Perception)
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)



    #Vigra Headers
    include_directories(
        include
    )
    file(GLOB_RECURSE VigraImpex include/impex/)
    add_library(VigraImpex ${VigraImpex})

    #LibXml2 Headers
    find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)

    #Armadillo Headedrs
    find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    #Boost Headers
    find_package(Boost 1.54.0 REQUIRED)



    add_executable(features_slic src/features_slic.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(features_slic
        VigraImpex
        ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

BTW: LibXml2, Armadillo and Boost are all dependencies of the library I am trying to use - **mlpack**. The command `find_pakcage(mlpack)` won't work because there is no `Findmlpack.cmake` file on my system anywhere, and I couldn't find one on the internet either.

Comment: You should probably add `include_directories(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR})` after the line `find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)`

Comment: Well, as of now I've simply gone with the (painful) hack of changing all `#include <libxml/*.h>` to `#include "*.h"` so that I could move forward with my project. I'll try out what you suggested as soon as I'm finished (probably two more days).

Comment: Ah yes, that worked perfectly! I have a follow-up question, though. How do you know what the name of the variable to use in `include_directories` will be? I had tried adding the line `include_directories(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS})` (based on the fact that a similar addition had worked for Armadillo) before and it didn't work.